# доработать слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.price-services__cards');
const parantCard = document.querySelector('.price-services__container');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.price-services-right');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.price-services-left');

cardsLength = allCards.length;

let currentSlide = 1;

const moveSlide = function () {
    allCards.forEach((cards, index) => {
        const offset = index - currentSlide;
        cards.classList.toggle('slide-active', Math.abs(offset) < 1);
        cards.style.transition = '.7s ease';

        if (currentSlide <= cardsLength / 2) {
            allCards[0].classList.remove('price-services__cards_first');
            allCards[cardsLength - 1].classList.add(
                'price-services__cards_last'
            );
        } else {
            //Если скролл вперёд, то первому элементу добавляется класс

            allCards[cardsLength - 1].classList.remove(
                'price-services__cards_last'
            );
            allCards[0].classList.add('price-services__cards_first');
        }
    });
    parantCard.style.transform = `translateX(${-currentSlide * 383}px)`;

    parantCard.style.transition = '.7s ease';
    console.log(parantCard);
};
// moveSlide(currentSlide);

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % cardsLength;

    moveSlide();
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    currentSlide = (currentSlide - 1 + cardsLength) % cardsLength;

    moveSlide();
});

moveSlide();
```

```css
.price-services {
    padding-top: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    &__main-container {
        width: 1160px;
        height: 454px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;

        &::before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

            width: 890px;
            height: 415px;
            border-radius: 890px;
            background: radial-gradient(
                43.25% 43.25% at 50% 50%,
                rgba(118, 0, 173, 0.4) 0%,
                rgba(24, 24, 24, 0.4) 100%
            );
        }
    }

    // .price-services__container

    &__container {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;

        width: 1190px;

        gap: 78px;

        padding-top: 34px;

        margin-bottom: 78px;
        margin-left: 428px;

        //
    }

    // .price-services__cards

    &__cards {
        border-radius: 30px;
        border: 3px solid $main-color;
        flex: 0 0 305px;
        height: 337px;

        padding: 48px 19px;

        z-index: 1;

        //
    }

    // .price-services__cards-header

    &__cards-header {
        font-size: 1.5rem;

        font-weight: 500;
        line-height: 122%;
        text-align: center;

        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    // .price-services__cards-text

    &__cards-text {
        text-align: center;
        font-family: $second-font;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 130%;

        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    // .price-services__cards-price

    &__cards-price {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 122%;
        text-align: center;

        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }

    // .price-services__cards-button

    &__cards-button {
        display: block;
        padding: 12px 55px;

        border-radius: 10px;
        background: $main-color;

        font-size: 1.125rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 122%;

        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

// .title-cards {
//     margin-bottom: 86px;
// }

.slide-active {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    overflow: hidden;
    // transition: 0.7s ease;
}

//

.price-services__cards_first {
    transform: translateX(2681px);
}

.price-services__cards_last {
    transform: translateX(-2681px);
}
```

```html
<section class="price-services">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="title title-cards">УСЛУГИ И СТОИМОСТЬ</h2>
                <div class="price-services__main-container">
                    <div class="price-services__container">
                        <!-- first card -->
                        <div
                            class="price-services__cards price-services__cards_first"
                        >
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                МНОГОСТРАНИЧНЫЙ <br />САЙТ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Состоит из нескольких
                                <br />страниц.Переключаться <br />можно в
                                пунктах меню.
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                20 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- second card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards slide-active">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ЛЕНДИНГ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Это посадочная страница с действиями
                                (зарегистрироваться, купить)
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                6 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- third card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ИНТЕРНЕТ-МАГАЗИН
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Может состоять из одной или нескольких страниц.
                                Создан для продаж
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                25 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- fourth card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ЛОГОТИПЫ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Нужен для любого бренда после ознакомления
                                предлагаю
                                <br />3 варианта на выбор
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                2 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- fifth card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ПОЛИГРАФИЯ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Презентации, визитки, чек-<br />листы,
                                меню,вывески, <br />листовки и др.
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                3 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- sixth card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                РЕКЛАМНЫЕ МАКЕТЫ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Цифровая реклама, карточки для маркетплейсов,
                                любая рекламная продукция
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                от 4 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- seventh card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ДИЗАЙН ПОД КЛЮЧ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Полный дизайн вашего <br />бизнеса. От логотипа
                                и <br />листовки до сайта
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                50 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio__arrows">
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="portfolio__arrow-left price-services-left"
                    ></button>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="portfolio__arrow-right price-services-right"
                    ></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: буду благодарен за помощь)

Comment: Это же чистая логика...слайдер работает с индексом, соответственно если индекс становится больше 6 - то делаете index = 1. и всё .... в обратную сторону почти также: если индекс -1, то делаете его "длина массива  - 1"

Comment: смысл в том, что при такой логике он перелистывает, а мне в итоге нужно, чтобы отображалось на экране.
последняя карточка слева , первая карточка по середине, вторая карточка справа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать такое поведение добавлением классов, которые бы изменяли позицию первого и последнего элемента в слайдере в зависимости от того, в какую сторону происходит скролл слайдера, или вместо классов добавлять или удалять свойство transform через JS.

```js
const allCards = document.querySelectorAll('.price-services__cards');

const parantCard = document.querySelector('.price-services__container');

const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.price-services-right');

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.price-services-left');

let cardsLength = allCards.length;

let currentSlide = 1;

const moveSlide = function () { //Если скролл назад, то последнему элементу добавляется класс
  allCards.forEach((cards, index) => {
      const offset = index - currentSlide;
      cards.classList.toggle('slide-active', Math.abs(offset) < 1);
  });

  if (currentSlide <= cardsLength / 2) {

    allCards[0].classList.remove('price-services__cards_first');
    allCards[cardsLength - 1].classList.add('price-services__cards_last');

  } else { //Если скролл вперёд, то первому элементу добавляется класс

    allCards[cardsLength - 1].classList.remove('price-services__cards_last');
    allCards[0].classList.add('price-services__cards_first');
  }
  
  //Второй вариант, можно вместо класса добавлять элементам свойство transform
  
 /* if (currentSlide <= cardsLength / 2) {

    allCards[0].style.removeProperty('transform');
    allCards[cardsLength - 1].style.transform = `translateX(${-cardsLength * 425}px)`;

  } else {

    allCards[cardsLength - 1].style.removeProperty('transform');
    allCards[0].style.transform = `translateX(${cardsLength * 425}px)`;
  }*/

  parantCard.style.transform = `translateX(${-(currentSlide - 1) * 425}px)`;
};

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % cardsLength;

  moveSlide();
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  currentSlide = (currentSlide - 1 + cardsLength) % cardsLength;

  moveSlide();
});

moveSlide();
```

```css
.price-services {
  padding-top: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

 .price-services__main-container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 .price-services__container {
  display: flex;
  width: 1200px;
  gap: 75px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 78px;
}

 .price-services__cards {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  min-width: 350px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 48px 19px;
}

 .price-services__cards-header {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 122%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

 .price-services__cards-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 130%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

 .price-services__cards-price {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 122%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

 .price-services__cards-button {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 55px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 122%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

 .title-cards {
  margin-bottom: 86px;
}

 .slide-active {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.price-services__cards_first {
  transform: translateX(2975px);
}

.price-services__cards_last {
  transform: translateX(-2975px);
}
```

```html
<section class="price-services">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="title title-cards">УСЛУГИ И СТОИМОСТЬ</h2>
                <div class="price-services__main-container">
                    <div class="price-services__container">

                        <!-- first card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards price-services__cards_first">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                МНОГОСТРАНИЧНЫЙ <br />САЙТ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Состоит из нескольких
                                <br />страниц.Переключаться <br />можно в
                                пунктах меню.
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                20 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- second card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards slide-active">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ЛЕНДИНГ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Это посадочная страница с действиями
                                (зарегистрироваться, купить)
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                6 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- third card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ИНТЕРНЕТ-МАГАЗИН
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Может состоять из одной или нескольких страниц.
                                Создан для продаж
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                25 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- fourth card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ЛОГОТИПЫ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Нужен для любого бренда после ознакомления
                                предлагаю
                                <br />3 варианта на выбор
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                2 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- fifth card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ПОЛИГРАФИЯ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Презентации, визитки, чек-<br />листы,
                                меню,вывески, <br />листовки и др.
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                3 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- sixth card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                РЕКЛАМНЫЕ МАКЕТЫ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Цифровая реклама, карточки для маркетплейсов,
                                любая рекламная продукция
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                от 4 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- seventh card -->
                        <div class="price-services__cards">
                            <h3 class="price-services__cards-header">
                                ДИЗАЙН ПОД КЛЮЧ
                            </h3>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-text">
                                Полный дизайн вашего <br />бизнеса. От логотипа
                                и <br />листовки до сайта
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-services__cards-price">
                                50 000 рублей
                            </p>
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                class="price-services__cards-button"
                            >
                                ЗАКАЗАТЬ
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portfolio-arrows">
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="portfolio-arrows__left price-services-left"
                    >←</button>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        class="portfolio-arrows__right price-services-right"
                    >→</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: все отлично работает, хотел ещё спросить, у меня появляется переход позади карточек , как его скрыть можно ?

Заранее благодарен, только вы мне и помогаете)

Comment: У меня не появляется перехода, вы изменяли стили или добавляли новые?

Comment: обновил код в самом запросе. У меня когда доходит до последней карточки. Как происходит переход этих карточек позади основных, и вот не знаю как скрыть видимость их перелистования. Может конечно я код ваш не корректно использовал. Буду благодарен за дальнейшую помощь. Это мой первый пэт проект, не судите строго меня, еще раз спасибо за вашу помощь!

Comment: я понял в чем проблема(переезд карточек был из за анимации), и если кому интересно, понял как решить основную проблему. Вместо того, чтобы карточки переезжали. Добавил в начало одну последнюю карточку, в конец первую и в итоге получилось то что нужно. Спасибо за помощь